# Xcode simulator crash after manually terminating my app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

When I double-click on the Home button and kill my app, the simulator kind of crashes and dispaly black screen and I have to run it again from Xcode.

I'm sure this is not normal. For example Safari doesn't do that.

Does anyone know what can cause this?

I cleared the method `viewWillDissappear`, `viewDidDissappear`, `viewWillUnload` and `viewDidUnload` and still didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're attached to the application's process from Xcode. When you terminate it in the simulator Xcode freaks out - I'm guessing you're getting the error `SigKill`. This is normal for running apps in the simulator.

Comment: yes! SigKill... ok phew... thanks, you just saved me a lot of nerves and ****ing around :D :)